# How to create a cron that runs every time it ends and how to prevent if there is another scheduled cron that could be running?

Tags: shell, scripting, cron

Please, I'm trying to do this, if you could help me to configure a cron (cronjob_1) that **starts at 6 a.m. and it runs every time it ends until midnight**, that is, 00:00 a.m. every Monday and Tuesday and every month. **And most importantly, how to prevent it from running** if there is another scheduled cron (cronjob_2) that might be running, until cronjob_1 can identify that there is no cronjob_2 running so that it can start running again?

```
00 06 * * 1 /bin/sh /app/cronjob_1.sh
00 06 * * 2 /bin/sh /app/cronjob_1.sh
...
00 08 * * 1 /bin/sh /app/cronjob_2.sh
00 10 * * 1 /bin/sh /app/cronjob_2.sh
00 08 * * 2 /bin/sh /app/cronjob_2.sh (it could be any time)
...
```

*I will greatly appreciate your help.*

Comment: It looks an awful lot like a daemon that restarts if stopped. What is that cronjob supposed to do?

Comment: create a temporary file while running; if it exists, exit; otherwise, run.  Should be simple enough using cron

Comment: @EduardoTrápani the cronjob calls a web address with curl.

Comment: @ILMostro_7 thanks for your answer, but how do you control the starting every time it ends, but only when it ends?

Comment: M. Trápani is right.  A restarting service that _is started and stopped by_ cron jobs at those two times is a better way to look at this.  One need not reinvent the mechanisms of service management, such as ensuring only one instance at a time and automatic restarts, with some rickety Heath Robinson device constructed out of flag files and cron, when one can just use service management.